# GE API icon color

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

There is a problem with the GE API when setting the color to blue. 
It seems to be the same problem here:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=313
Where the tip of the icon turns blue but not the body.

I have the following basic code:

```
var propIcon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/tree.png';
var icon = ge.createIcon('');
icon.setHref(propIcon);
var style = ge.createStyle('');
style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
var colorMode = style.getIconStyle().getColor();
colorMode.set("fffdf802");
```

The icon simply stays green.
It works with some other colors.

I suspect the blending of the tree.png (green) with my blue not working properly.

How can it be fixed? I need to use this icon.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use white color icons.

http://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx#GoogleEarthWhiteIcons